# jscript ajax send data to remote server and get response not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here is my code

EDIT :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "http://geturl.orgfree.com/fetch/adfly.php",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "JSONP",
    data: { url: "http:// adf.ly/7fs" , method: "1" },
    success: function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
        document.write(msg);
    },
});
</script>
```

it is not giving any response. i have tried it online as well as on localhost
it does say waiting for geturl.orgfree.com but nothing.
please help!

Thanks, i have added http:// but still not working

Comment: your request responds with a blank result, so how do you expect it to work? http://geturl.orgfree.com/fetch/adfly.php?url=adf.ly/7fs

Comment: sorry. i need to add http:// before adf.ly, my bad :P. then it gives output. but it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `http://` to the data URL.

```
$.ajax({
    data: { url: "http://"+"adf.ly/7fs" , method: "1" },
    ...
});
```

(You can remove the `"+"` between the 2 parts, only SO wouldn't let me post the answer with them together)